# What is the right approach to upload the data into HBase from Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, hbase

I am working on writing a Spark job which reads the data from the Hive and store in HBase for real time access. The executor makes the connection with HBase, what is the right approach to insert the data into. I have thought of following two approaches.

Which one is more appropriate or is there any other approach?

1. Write data directly from Spark Job to Hbase
2. Write data from Spark to HDFS and later move it to Hbase

Comment: Are you talking about online/realtime job or some offline/batch job?

Comment: Thanks Shay for reply: The intention here is to know, what is the best way to insert the data into HBase?

Comment: It really depends on the use case - bulk load with `HFileOutputFormat2` is better for batch processing, and for realtime/online apps you should use `TableOutputFormat`

Comment: The quicket way is to generate HFiles in map-reduce and bulk load them. It's fast, reliable and quite flexible. So don't use Spark :)